# How to get text value form select field using SuiteScript 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm building custom page using Suitelet in Netsuite.  I added select field and field options. How could I get selected text value from the select field.

I tried using `request.getParamter('custpage_select_field')` in  the POST request, but it didn't  work.

Comment: Other than the typo in `getParameter()`, that seems to be the correct way to access field values in the POST.  Without seeing additional code, there's not a lot of troubleshooting we can do for you.  Can you update your question to add some sample code?

Comment: I used with field changed client script and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

request.getParamter gets you the script parameters, which are specified on your script deployment.

To retrieve screen field values that have been passed from the GET section, you should be using:

```
request.parameters.custpage_select_field
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

U have to parse the request then call `request.parameters.custpage_select_field`

```
var parameters = (typeof request_.parameters === 'object') ? request_.parameters : JSON.parse(request_.parameters);
```